# Beautiful soup different output for UK and US sites

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have mainly used this site to find solutions so far, however I am struggling to find a solution as to why I get different soup objects for US and UK versions of the same site, even though they are pretty much the same when using inspect element or developer tools on the websites.

I am in the UK if that is possibly a factor, when parsing ebay US(.com) I get the desired result with regards to the tag names, but when using ebay UK a lot of the html code tag names etc seem to have changed.

The following code is an example of how I create the soup object and find listing elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xcomputer+keyboard.TRS0&_nkw=computer+keyboard&_sacat=0"


res = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')


for listing in soup.findAll('li', {'class': 's-item'}):
    try:
        link = listing.find('a', {'class': 's-item__link'})
        name = listing.find("h3", {"class": "s-item__title"}).get_text()
        price = listing.find("span", {"class": "s-item__price"}).get_text()
        print(link.get('href'))
        print(name)
        print(price + "\n")

    except:
        pass

>>>https://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-WIRED-STYLISH-SLIM-QWERTY-KEYBOARD-UK-LAYOUT-FOR-PC-DESKTOP-COMPUTER-LAPTOP/392095538686?epid=2298009317&hash=item5b4ab71dfe:g:Zp0AAOSwowBbZw7U
>>>USB WIRED STYLISH SLIM QWERTY KEYBOARD UK LAYOUT FOR PC DESKTOP COMPUTER LAPTOP
>>>$7.15
```

So an example of the issue I am having: 
If I was using the US site (if you change the above URL to .com) and want to find the listing titles I can use `findAll('li', {'class': 's-item__title'})` from the soup object

However if I am using the UK site (above URL) I can only find the titles using `findAll('li', {'class': 'lvtitle'})` This is also the same if I wanted to retrieve the list of listings For the US soup object I can simply use 's-item', but this is not the case for the UK soup object.

I'm pretty new to programming so apologies for my poor explanation.

EDIT: The above code has been edited to show a working script. Using the above code when I run the script on ebay US I get the correct result (link, name, price of each listing) if I run the same script with the ebay UK URL it returns no results. So it does not seem to be due to a mistake in the script itself, the soup object is different for me, but not for others it seems.

Comment: You haven't given enough code to replicate what you're seeing, I am getting an empty list returned for both URL's. I would hazard a guess at the likes of GDPR and other privacy protocol differences between Europe and USA.

Comment: Your question seems to say ”two sites look the same visually, and the HTML is similar, only they have different CSS styles, so when I select by styles to find the title I have to use different code”. So what is the question?

Comment: @BSQL GFPR isn’t a reason to change the structure of a page or the look-and-feel (e.g. CSS). GDPR applies globally based on the citizenship of the user not the URL of the site. Global firms that have different domains in different countries, with a team customising the content and look-and-feel in different countries, are very likely to change the promotions and CSS on their sites. They do this to maximise engagement. In the UK we don’t celebrate Thanksgiving and the USA doesn’t celebrate St. George’s Day. One country has Superbowl and the other has the Six Nations. Google customises on this.

Answer (score 1):

> even though they are pretty much the same when using inspecting the HTMl on the websites

1. Programming lesson that you learn fairly early. Pretty much the same != to the same. In software, the difference between a program running and failing can be one char out of a million.
2. You are using CSS selectors to target various elements on the page. CSS does the styling of the pages. However, what do you notice about the websites (images are attached at the bottom)? **The styling is very different and thus at least some of the CSS is different.** To a certain level, these are different websites and thus will need separate ways to scrape them (it could be as small as making the target CSS a variable or as large as completely seperate programs just with shared functions).
3. I am a bit perplexed that you cannot use `s-item__title` for both. I see it in the CSS of both the USA and UK eBay sites. Check that you are doing it properly, perhaps by posting your code (you must post code) in a new question specifically asking about this.
4. Companies like eBay are not really pleased with people scraping their websites and probably take measures to defeat such attempts. Changing up the CSS so that scrapers do not have consistent targets is certainly one method they might use to prevent it from occurring.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the tips. 
Point 3 is exactly my question, I cannot figure out why this is happening?
I have updated my initial question which now shows a full script which run perfectly fine on the US site but not the UK

Answer (score 0):

I recently personally created a project to fetch data from different websites and ebay was one of them using BeautifulSoup. I can tell you from experience that fetching data from ebay is a struggle and behaves in unexpected manner and would give you unexpected results.

One thing you can do is go to that url and right click to inspect the page and see the html layout to see the results you are getting and how can you go around that (maybe by changing your queries in the url). I know you have already done that but the html in their web page is really big and there is probably some small differences that you didn't catch. Perhaps a good idea is to compare the html from the US and the UK outputs as there could be some tag differences between the two and based on the tags in the UK website you can change your findAll method.

Also another (more formal way) to fetch data is by using the ebay API and here is the link for a quick start guide for the US website https://developer.ebay.com/tools/quick-start